# Set pan paramater in AVMutableAudioMix

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset

I know it's possible to set the volume of an `AVMutableAudioMix` using something like

```
let inputMixerParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters()
inputMixerParameters.setVolume(0.1, at: kCMTimeZero)
inputMixerParameters.trackID = assetTrack.trackID
var inputParametersArray = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()
inputParametersArray.append(inputMixerParameters)

let mix = AVMutableAudioMix()
mix.inputParameters = inputParametersArray
```

But how am I supposed to do to set the pan value of a `AVMutableAudioMix`? I saw that the `AVAudioMixing` protocol conforms to the `AVAudioStereoMixing` protocol with the pan property but I don't know how to use it.